# Backbone.js, splitting up files in legacy app

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am using backbone.js in a legacy app to rewrite separate pages into individual bits of backbone work.

I am not using any routing and it is not a total single page application.

Only certain pages are individual backbone.js applicaitons.

At the moment I have all my backbone javasript in one file for each page that uses it which is painful to work on.

Would it be wise to use something like requirejs on a page by page basis or is there something better I could do in order to split the page up in development and serve one page in production?

Answer (score 1):

That depends largely on what your existing codebase looks like.

RequireJS is a great tool...if your existing code is set up to support it, or you have a small enough codebase to be able to convert it without breaking everything. However, not all legacy JS code is, especially if it's part of a larger system (I personally ran into this problem with a Backbone project I'm working on). If you can, then by all means, make use of it. The big advantage, as far as I know, with RequireJS is that it doesn't actually fetch and load the Javascript files until you need them. So you can have one RequireJS call that's in all of your pages, and only download what you need, when you need it.

There are other ways, however, to combine your Javascript code at production time, which, again, depends greatly on your setup. Many content management systems include "minify" scripts that handle it automatically for all of your Javascript files. You can also do it "by hand" with [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/), [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), or one of the many other minification tools out there. (You can also do it "really by hand", and develop in multiple files and combine them via copy+paste, but that's really more work than is necessary.)

Regardless of how you go about doing it, I highly recommend breaking your projects into multiple files (not only into a file for different projects, but multiple files within the projects, to hold each view and models if they have significant code). It makes it infinitely easier to maintain.